# Android - public method setMobileDataEnabled in ConnectivityManager not available in SDK

Tags: android, connectivity

i'm trying to use the method setMobileDataEnabled of the ConnectivityManager class, using SDK 2.2.
According to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java/?v=source  this method is declared public but with @hide is not available in the SDK and in Eclipse.

In order to bypass the hiding I wrote the following function to toggle the mobile data connection on/off.

```
public void setMobileData(boolean toBeEnabled){

        Object myObj= getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) myObj;

        Class c = null;
        try {
            c = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        Method m = null;
        try {
            m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        } catch (SecurityException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        Object mobileDataEnabled=null;
        if (m!=null){
            m.setAccessible(true);
            Type res_of_m=  m.getGenericReturnType();
            Type[] pars_of_m=  m.getGenericParameterTypes();
            try {
                mobileDataEnabled = (m.invoke(cm));
                if (mobileDataEnabled!=null)
                    if (mobileDataEnabled.equals(!toBeEnabled)){
                        Method m2 = null;
                        try {
                            int index=0;
                            boolean method_found=false;
                            Method[] available_methods= c.getDeclaredMethods();
                            for (Method method : available_methods) {
                                // following line doesn't work
                                // method.getName()=="setMobileDataEnabled" 
                                if (method.getName().contains("setMobileDataEnabled")) 
                                {
                                    method_found=true;
                                }

                                if (method_found==false) 
                                    index++;
                            }
                            // following line doesn't work
                            //m2 = c.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled"); 
                            m2 = (c.getDeclaredMethods())[index];
                            if (m2!=null){
                                m2.setAccessible(true);
                                m2.invoke(cm,toBeEnabled);
                            }
                        } catch (SecurityException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

To make it working I also added the android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" in the manifest and installed in /system/app according to [Android: Add app to firmware, use WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632449/android-add-app-to-firmware-use-write-secure-settings).

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
   try {
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final Class connectivityManager = Class.forName(cm.getClass()
                .getName());

        final Method[] methods = connectivityManager.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (final Method method : methods) {
            if (MLauncherConnectivityManager.SET_MOBILE_DATA_ENABLED
                    .equals(method.getName())) {
                method.invoke(cm, true);
            }
        }

    } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Class", e.getMessage());
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("Class", e.getMessage());
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Class", e.getMessage());
    } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e("Class", e.getMessage());
    }
```