# Distribute android app from my own server

Tags: android, distribution

I have developed a android app. i just want to distribute it from my own server. i dont want to put it on google play. is it possible? if yes, how can i?

Comment: Check out this previous discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841095/install-and-update-android-app-from-my-own-website-and-not-market

Answer (score 9):

### Steps:

- Configure the *MIME-TYPE* on Web server for *apk* as *application/vnd.android.package-archive*
- To do this, you must first *prepare your application for release* in
  the normal way.
- *Host the release-ready APK file* on your
  website and provide a download link to users.

### How it works:

When users browse to the download link from their Android-powered devices, the file is downloaded and *Android system automatically starts installing* it on the device.

### Downsides:

- However, the *installation* process will start *automatically* only if
  the user has configured their *Settings* to *allow* the installation of
  apps from *unknown sources*.

  [image: settings]
- if you want to *monetize* your application you will have to process and
  track all financial transactions yourself and you will not be able to
  use Google Play's *[In-app Billing service](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)* to sell *in-app products*.

  [image: in app billing service]
- You will not be able to use the *[Licensing service](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)* to help prevent
  unauthorized installation and use of your application.

  [image: google license service]

### Note:

Having said the downsides of it ,its up to you decide which one to stick

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html#unknown-sources)

Comment: Can anyone help me with this as changing the MIME type does not help, want to do the same as : https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/alternative-distribution.html#websites OR as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Have you configured Settings to allow the installation of apps from unknown sources ?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to upload the .apk file to your own server then point the link to it and everyone can download and install it if the user have enabled the option "**install from other sources**" in their device.

Comment: It also helps to have the Web server configured to serve APK files as having the MIME type of `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Can anyone help me with this as changing the MIME type does not help, want to do the same as : developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/… OR as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @Custadian: If you are having a problem configuring your server, ask a question on https://serverfault.com.

Comment: Actually, I tried by configuring the server and app is not getting installed automatically. My question is in Google's official doc about "Distributing through a website" is saying that after opting in for 'installation via unknown source'; the installation will happen automatically. They mentioned the word install not download, but only download is happening not installation.  https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/alternative-distribution.html#websites