# Sync hosted Apk in local server with Play store version

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-update-app

We have an app published to Google Play, and need to be able to download it in an internet restricted environment.

So after hosting that Apk on local server (as mentioned in [Distribute android app from my own server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776552/distribute-android-app-from-my-own-server)), is there a way to have the local server Apk to sync with Apk from Play, after publishing the updates to Play only.

Other than posting the same Apk to both places simultaneously.

Comment: this could help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931590/download-app-from-google-play-programatically you still have to implement a code or script on ur server that will download the APK regularly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot simply publish updates from local server to Google Play dynamically. Even if you spend a lot of time to do it programatically you will have to update your script **every time** Google Play does upgrade (its kinda often).

But you can write separate `service` which will check for updates on Google Play and replace existing apk on your local server.

For example there is [unofficial existing api](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api) for getting apk from Google Play, so your own service can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, will check it.