# Why cant my android application get certain privileges despite being mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am writing an android application to which I have granted the following privileges by adding the following lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS">
    </uses-permission>
```

But I am getting the following error in my LogCat. I am also unable to delete packages from the SD Card, and I have a feeling it is due to the lack of privilege to do so.

```
07-28 07:37:32.281: WARN/PackageManager(61): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES to package com.org.EasyUpload (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)
07-28 07:37:32.281: WARN/PackageManager(61): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES to package com.org.EasyUpload (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)
07-28 07:37:32.295: WARN/PackageManager(61): Not granting permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES to package com.org.EasyUpload (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)
07-28 07:37:32.301: WARN/PackageManager(61): Not granting permission android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER to package com.org.EasyUpload (protectionLevel=2 flags=0xbe46)
07-28 07:37:32.301: WARN/PackageManager(61): Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS to package com.org.EasyUpload (protectionLevel=2 flags=0xbe46)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476600/why-are-these-permissions-being-refused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all permissions can be successfully requested by the application: Android uses `permissionLevel`s ("normal", "dangerous", "signature" and "signatureOrSystem") that are [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll install a signed APK and see if I can get the delete Package permission for my app.

Comment: Now there's also "development" protectionLevel (it isn't noted in all documents though): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html