# how to install android application in factory test mode

Tags: android, android-manifest, factory-pattern

I am trying to install android application in factory test mode. I make device(beagle board) to enter into factory test mode with corresponding android froyo build. It is entering factory test mode successfully, and when I try to install an application from ADB shell, it shows the following error

> (ERROR : could not find package manager,Is the system running?)

I am using required permission in manifest file. But it is showing above error. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This permission is granted only to the system applications or the application that is signed with "Firmware key"(The key used to sign the system applications). 
If u have firmware key then add this tag in AndroidManifest and sign ur application with that key.

```
     android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

U can get firmware key if u r working with device manufacturer ow forget it!!
Refer this::

[enter link description here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3af09c76f3ba8d96/d314c4adaaa217c4?show_docid=d314c4adaaa217c4&pli=1)

Comment: I heard like, device applications run in Factory test mode having root permissions . Is it compulsory to sign the application even to install it in Factory Test mode?.

Comment: Ofcourse! See, to run application in Factory test mode u need FACTORY_TEST system level permission. System level permissions are not granted to normal user. http://www.krvarma.com/2010/10/security-permissions-in-android/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476600/why-are-these-permissions-being-refused

Answer (score -1):

i think it is related to the certificate you are using. you require a manufacturer certificate to sign your app in order to access this kind of permission