# SecurityException with Android

Tags: android, security, exception, permissions, manifest

I have this code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELPHONY_SERVICE);
Class clase = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());  
Method m = clase.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");  
m.setAccesible(true);  
ITelephony it = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  
it.supplyPIN("1111");
```

I have a SecurityException when I try to invoke the method `*supplyPIN("1111")*`. 
The error message is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10066 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
```

In my `Manifest.xml` I have the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Insure that it matches this string at this URL:
[MODIFY_PHONE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)

Answer (score 0):

ITelephony is an internal class of android, you should not be using it

Comment: My app need supply a pin to Android and check this pin. Do you know another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer: [How to grant system permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063549/how-to-grant-system-permission)

You need to follow a similar approach for the android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

If you have done this already, refer to more link on the above page that gives more details on how permission are used.

Hope this helps.