# Nfc Toggle in Android 4.x+?

Tags: android, toggle, nfc

I know it is programmatically possible to disable NFC in Gingerbread, but has anyone managed to create a work around to accomplish the same for ICS and above?

I'm ok if it involves changing the source code of the OS also if someone has ventured into that :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Gingerbread 2.3.5 an app needs the special permission `"android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"` to change the state of NFC. Normally, only apps signed by Google can have this permission, but I assume that if you root your device, you can probably circumvent that by adding your app to the system image or adding your signature key to some list that is stored somewhere. This answer also seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477237/1202968