# Exception in android manifest file permission

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-permissions

I got exception in android manifest file.
 I have added following permissions:

```
1. uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

2. uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I got 
"Permission is only granted to system apps" error. How to fix it. Before it was working fine.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13531365/165674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't fix it. As mentioned:

```
 "Permission is only granted to system apps"
```

This mean, no ordinary app can use the permissions. At least, not without rooting the device.