# Permission is only granted to system app, in Manifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I want to add this permission to my Android manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
> ```

But after I paste this permission in my manifest, it tests red underline and says:

> permission is only granted to system apps

What can I do?

Comment: What API call are you using that requires this permission?

Comment: @A--C I'm trying this tutorial. http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html

Comment: I can see why this app needs the permission. Have a a look at the comments though, other people have had this issue, at least on gingerbread.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it just by doing Project->Clean. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13531632/165674

Comment: @DheerajV.S.Thanks for your mention, but I used another solution! I copied all manifest content in clipboard, then erased all manifest from eclipse and then paste it to manifest from workspace! and it worked! :)

Comment: try this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app

Comment: @Noman Wow! Good solution! i'll keep it in my mind, for my next projects. thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission is granted to system apps only.

For your information, there are 2 types of Android apps: system & user

> ***User apps*** are just all your normal app installations through the Google Play Store, Amazon Appstore or sideloading. These go into the /data partition of your Android phone, which is the part of the internal memory made available for user data and apps.
>
> ***System apps*** are basically the apps that come pre-installed with your ROM. In a standard Android user environment, the user doesn’t have write access to the /system partition and thus, installing or uninstalling system apps directly isn’t possible.
>
> In order to install an app as a system app on your Android device,
> ***your device must either be rooted or have a custom recovery installed (or both)***.

That being said, that error is actually wrong because you have a valid code and compilation should work. It would be better if it gave a warning instead. In Eclipse you can easily fix it. Just go to:

> **Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.**

Find **`ProtectedPermission`** from the list and set the severity to something other than error(info for example). This way your project will still compile.

Answer (score 6):

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is a system-only permission. System Apps are either pre-installed into a system folder or compiled by a manufacturer using their security certificate.

Hence, if you are trying to do this you are trying to use API which are no longer supported. With Android versions 2.3+ you can monitor incoming calls, but blocking is not allowed (i think from the link you posted thats what you're trying to do).

Android issues if you need to follow: [Issue 15022](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15022) and [Issue 14789](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14789)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to block incoming calls, and so this problem really sucks.

Comment: So, how the are some apps on Play store which can do call blocking?

Comment: I dont they block calls. they say they do, but all what they can do is notify the user (when a blocked number calls), but cannot completely block it. All of this of course in Android 2.3+ versions.

Answer (score 4):

This error appears in SDK 19 onwards, when you change the manifest.
Do Project Clean and Build.
It should clear this error.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 2):

just clean your project it will be fine  like this :

project > Clean...

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the system level permission device developer not grant this so application development tools also warn against this so you have to

> Simply Clean project & Rebuild this is it

Answer (score 1):

**There are four types of Permission**

```
Regular
Dangerous
Signed
Signed or System
```

`The first two can be used by Simple Apps` Other two can only be used by the app which is build in framework

Answer (score 0):

Find ProtectedPermission from the list in

```
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.
```

and set the severity to something other than error(info for example). This way your project will still compile.