# Why show error Permission is only granted to system apps in android manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I added these permissions to my app some months ago, and Eclipse never showed and error:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Today, however, I edited the Android manifest file, and now it shows an error:

`Permission is only granted to system apps`

Why?  How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Try clean+build. That had worked for me

Comment: clean +build , it 's ok. But I open and edit anything in file androidmanifest , it show error again.

Comment: Well, clean+build had solved the problem in my case. Try restarting eclipse after closing the project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13531632/646806

Comment: I had the same problem.  I'm not sure why Eclipse is doing this but here is a workaround:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457720/android-manifest-file-breaks-after-adding-a-permission

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is doing you a favor -- that really is an error. Only apps signed with Google's signing key can install or delete apps.

You can probably suppress those error messages by configuring your lint options in Eclipse (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16457801/338479), but unless you actually work for Google and have access to their signing key, you can't set those permissions.

Well, maybe on a rooted device, but your app won't exactly be portable.

Edit: or did you change your SDK target version? Perhaps older versions of Android allowed you to have those permissions, but now you've targeted a version that doesnt?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.
```

In the list find an entry with `ID = ProtectedPermission.` Set the Severity to something lower than Error. This way you can still compile the project using Eclipse.

In Android Studio:

```
File -> Settings -> Inspections
```

Under Android Lint, locate Using system app permission. Either uncheck the checkbox or choose a Severity lower than Error.